# preg_replace in PHP cant replace '`'

Tags: php, regex, yii, preg-replace

I try to remov this ` symbol from string. I try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('`', '', $string);
```

But get:

`No ending delemiter '`' found`

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `preg_replace` is regex. `str_replace` is a string. Don't use `preg_*` if you don't need/know what regex is. `$string = str_replace('`', '', $string)` is what you want. This would've been searchable by using [Google](http://www.google.com) (it's the biggest search engine in the world - I'm surprised you haven't heard of it) and searching for "*string replace php*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = str_replace("`", "", $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex delimiter is '/'. Change the line to:

`` $string = preg_replace('/`/', '', $string); ``

Comment: While the fix works, this is a horrible fix. It's like a mechanic explaining to someone how much glue to use to keep the engine in place or the same mechanic explaining exactly how much you can dillute your petrol with water before the engine starts choking. `str_replace` is *much* better. Also, the regex delimiter isn't `/`. It's whatever you'd like. `preg_replace('a\`a', '', $string)` works too.